# DllImport how to get single values by reference

Tags: c#, dllimport, ref, intptr

What's the appropiate signature/marshall attribute to be able to get output params using pointers params? So far I tried this:

```
// Function to calculate the norm of vector. !0 on error.
// int err_NormVec(int size, double * vector, double * norm)
[DllImport("vectors.dll")]
int err_NormVec(int size, double[] vector, ref double norm)
```

The previous approach doesn't pop back the value to .NET from C. I also tried to use pinned GCHandle, with the IntPtr signature.

```
[DllImport("vectors.dll")]
int err_NormVec(int size, double[] vector, IntPtr norm)

public void doSomething()
{
   double norm = 0;
   // ...
   GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(norm, GCHandleType.Pinned);
   int status = err_NormVec(vector.Lenght, vector, handle.AddrOfPinnedObject());
   // ... clean gchandle, check status and so on
}
```

In this case I got the value back but on the GCHandle.Target, not on the original norm. Which is annoying. I would like to be able to pin the intptr of the norm it self not just a copy.

What is the appropiate signature to return a value using a pointer? Is there a supported way to get a IntPtr to an int value?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm using win64. Which unveiled some bad practices that use to work luckily on win32 apps.

Comment: Show us the implementation (or at least the signature) of `err_NormVec`.  You don't need to pin a double to use it as an out parameter, `ref` will suffice.

Comment: @leppie: No, I'm not, are you?  I see a C# signature interop, I see no native code here.  You would just assume it is correct then?

Comment: @EdS.: In the comment above the first C# snippet. No?

Comment: @leppie:.... and so it is, sorry (though you don't have to be a jerk about it).  The implementation would be nice if possible though.

Comment: Regarding the IntPtr problems I think is caused by autoboxing, as the GCHandle expects and object. Hence the double is converted to a new double. Should be able to validate later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me (as it should):

```
//C++ DLL (__stdcall calling convention)
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void Foo(double *result) {
    *result = 1.2;
}

//C#    
class Program
{
    [DllImport( "Snadbox.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall )]
    static extern void Foo( ref double output );

    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        double d = 0;           
        Foo( ref d );

        Console.WriteLine( d ); // prints "1.2"         
    }
}
```

Passing the `double` using the `ref` keyword is sufficient.  So, I am led to believe that there is something wrong (or misunderstood) in the implementation.  Can you post the implementation for us?

Also, perhaps you are building the C++ version using the default calling convention (`cdecl`), but .NET is using `StdCall`.  Have you made sure that these line up?  You may crash if they are mixed, but there is no guarantee.  For instance, in my example, if I change the C++ side to `cdecl` then the out parameter is read back as 0.

Comment: The implementation is insignificant imo, this is just an example, as in reality it's a much complex library. If you want so an implementation will be: int err_NormVec(int size, double[] vector, double * norm)(*norm=0;for(int i=0;i<size;++i){norm+=vector[i]*vector[i];}*norm=sqrt(*norm);return 0;)

Comment: @fprades.bbva: Well, and I don't mean to sound rude, but your opinion has little weight as you don't know why this isn't working.  I have shown you that a simplified example does work, so something else is wrong and you haven't given us enough information to know what that is. Also, the snippet you gave me is wrong as you are adding to the pointer itself without dereferencing it.

Comment: That's what would expect to work as well. However for some reason doesn't do the trick in x64 runtime. Odd. Maybe I missed something with all the trial and error.

Comment: @fprades.bbva: I build everything to target x64 as well (should have noted that).  The double type is the same size between languages.

Comment: Ed S. That worked fine. I got sidetrack with a similar problem with ref arrays, which crash my app. Those I can manage with GCHandle safely. Thanks for the help, and patience.